# How to approximate numerically the gradient of the function on a triangular mesh

Tags: vector-analysis, finite-element-method

Given an arbitrary (lets say 2D) triangular mesh, with known $(x_i,y_i)$ locations of points, and numerical values of a function $f$ on them (either in the nodes, or in the centroids of the triangles, doesn't matter) [like this random example](https://i0.wp.com/www.bugman123.com/Engineering/FEM-triangles.jpg), how can I obtain a numerical approximation of the direction and modulus of the gradient in the nodes?

I can get directional gradients to adjacent nodes or elements, but I don't know how to join them to create a general gradient. I have the feeling that this will involve some sort of least squares solution.

PD:  if its relevant, we can assume linear functions on the triangles.

EDIT: I am unaware of the terminology, but as a initial test I can check if the gradient approximates linearly and quadratically the real gradient (by testing it against a known plane and parabola). Currently reading more on this.

Comment: Just found [this method on GC.SE.](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/8835/calculating-the-gradient-of-a-triangular-mesh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idea is based on @PiotrHughes' answer, which unfortunately does not provide good results even for the simple case of a linear function.

**Idea:** The idea is following: We want to compute the gradient at $P_0 = (x_0,y_0)$ which has edges to $P_i = (x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,2,3,...n$. Let us consider the unit vectors $d_i$ pointing from $P_0$ to $P_i$, so let $r_i = P_i - P_0$ and  $d_i = \frac{1}{||r_i||}(r_i)$.

Then the scalar product $\nabla f(x_0,y_0) \cdot d_i$ is the directional derivative in the direction $d_i$. These directional derivatives can be approximated by $$\nabla f(x_0,y_0) \cdot d_i \approx \frac{f(x_i,y_i)-f(x_0,y_0)}{||r_i||}$$

This gives us an equation for each edge, and if we have at least two non-colinear edges we can solve this system for $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ using least squares.

**Implementation:**
We can simplify this system to

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1-x_0 & y_1-y_0 \\ x_2-x_0 & y_2-y_0 \\  \vdots & \vdots \\ x_n - x_0 & y_n - y_0 \end{bmatrix} \nabla f(x_0,y_0) = \begin{bmatrix} f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_0,y_0) \\ f(x_2,y_2) - f(x_0,y_0) \\ \vdots  \\ f(x_n,y_n) - f(x_0,y_0)  \end{bmatrix}$$

**Convergence:** The only approximation we made is the use of the finite differences for the approximation of the directional derivatives. Assuming we have a regular and quasi uniform family of meshes these should converge with the known order. And it certainly provides exact results if $f$ is linear.

---

EDIT: Equivalently we can rewrite the equation from above as

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1-x_0 & y_1-y_0 & 1\\
 x_2-x_0 & y_2-y_0 & 1\\  
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots  \\
 x_n - x_0 & y_n - y_0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \nabla f(x_0,y_0) \\ f(x_0,y_0)\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} f(x_1,y_1)  \\ f(x_2,y_2)  \\ \vdots  \\ f(x_n,y_n)  \end{bmatrix}$$

Now it becomes very apparent that we're just fitting a plane through the surrounding points. Which was what I suggested as a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2628057/109451).

Comment: This answer is, in a plane, equally as good as your other answer, but this one also works on boundary nodes.

Comment: To add as extra info: The bottom answer in here is equivalent to the Prewitt operator in a regular mesh. If a weigthed least squares is performed, with weigths $1/r^2$, then its equivalent to a Sobel operator.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: *We found a new in my opinion more elegant solution, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2632616/109451).*

Another way is first computing the gradient on each triangle: $\nabla f|_T = [a,b]$ where

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\  x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\  x_3 & y_3 & 1  \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} f(x_1,y_1) \\  f(x_2,y_2)\\ f(x_3,y_3)  \end{bmatrix}$$

(we are fitting a plane $p(x,y) = ax+by+c$ on each triangle).

To compute the gradient at each node we just have to use a weighted average of all triangles that contain that node. We can do that by using the angle $\alpha_{n,T}$ of each triangle $T$ at our node $n$.

$$\nabla f_{n} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{T \in N} \alpha_{n,T}\nabla f|_T$$

Alternatively you can weigh each $\nabla f|_T$ by the area of the corresponding triangle (and normalize via the total area of the surrounding triangles). This has the advantage that we can also reuse the weights. Both methods do have the disadvantage that you also need to know all elements the given node is contained in, not only the edges.

---

Another method that just uses knowledge about the edges is fitting $p(x,y) = ax+by+c$ (via least squares) to all points that have edges to our node. This again is not very suitable for non-regular meshes.

Comment: Weighting by the inverse of area would be better than weighting by area. The larger the area, the farther away the other corners of the triangle are, which should weaken their influence, not increase it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Can you think of a concrete example where this produces a better result? I think when we have a large triangle that e.g. has gradient zero, then it would make sense for the approximations of the gradient and the corresponding nodes to be close to zero too.

Comment: The only concrete examples I can think of where it wouldn't produce a better result are those where the triangles are all roughly the same size or the function is close to constant. Try $f(x,y) = \frac 1{xy}$, with a fine-grained mesh for $x, y < 1$, but very course-grained for $x > 1, y > 1$. Now $$\nabla f(1,1) = (1,1)$$. For triangles whose other vertices are $< 1$, the small triangles will be very close to $(1,1)$ in gradient, for the large triangles on the other side, their gradients will be much closer to $(0,0)$. But they will have the large areas, not the small triangles.

Comment: But a better approach would not be to weight by area at all. Gradient is a local property. The farther the other points are from the point in question, the less reliable the estimate of gradient you will get from them will be. But area - even inverse area - doesn't correspond very well with distance. Weighting by the inverse of the max length of the two sides meeting at your target vertex would be better.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am test the different approaches proposed here and testing them with an arbitrary mesh with different amount of details, by applying a known plane/parabola as $f$. I suggest you add your idea as an answer

Comment: And another approach is the "cotangent" formula, which has its own nice properties. But until you decide on an interpolation scheme, you're just testing randomness. :(

Comment: I will share some nice statistics comparing this and the other method, but while this one seem to be x4 slower to me, it does quite well for a plane/parabolla, while Piotr's method does worse.

Comment: @JohnHughes but, if I chose the interpolation scheme the same as this one  (i.e. the value of $f$ in the nodes is computed with the values of the elements with angular weighting), then this method is valid, no?

Answer (score 3):

The key thing you need to do is search "discrete differential geometry", which is essentially all about topics like this.

A quick-and-dirty answer that works pretty well for well-behaved meshes (i.e., ones where the valence of each vertex is pretty near 6, rather than being, say, 14...) and where triangles are more or less equilateral (no angles less than about 20 degrees, say), is this:

$$
\nabla f (v) = \sum_{u\in N(v)} \left( f(u) - f(v) \right),
$$
where $N(v)$ is the set of vertices that are adjacent to $v$ (i.e. vertices $u$ with the property that $uv$ is an edge of the mesh).

Comment: Ah, yes, however I can certainly not assume this. As I am not really doing FEM, just using FEM-type meshes, I am good (and actually in some cases I look for) with triangles with ugly aspect ratios, or nodes with high valences. Thanks for they key words though!

Answer (score 3):

This will be a somewhat "brute force" approach. The error in this approximation will scale as $\mathcal{O}(h)$ where $h$ is the mesh size.

Take a point $(x_0, y_0)$ with $i$ neighbors. We can compute derivatives in the direction of neighbors by:

$$\vec{f_i'} \approx \frac{f(x_0, y_0) - f(x_i, y_i)}{r_i} \begin{bmatrix}
           (x_0 - x_i)/r_i \\
           (y_0 - y_i)/r_i
         \end{bmatrix}$$

where $r$ the distance is given by $\sqrt{(x_0 - x_i)^2 + (y_0 -y_i)^2}$.

From here: you have $i$ approximations for the gradient in the point. Take a weighted average of the the approximations (where weights are defined by the distance such that the closes points have the most influence)

$$\vec{f_{\text{final}}'} = \left(\sum_i \frac{1}{r_i}\right)^{-1} \left(\sum_i \frac{\vec{f_i'}}{r_i}\right)$$

Comment: Yes, I'll correct it now. We want the direction vector to have length one.

Comment: This method unfortunatley does not even converge to the actual result if we consider a linear function $f$. To understand why it is probably easiest to consider the function $f(x,y) = x$ and e.g. $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0), (x_1,y_1) = (-1,0), (x_2,y_2) = (0,-1), (x_3,y_3) = (1,1)$.

Comment: Based on your idea we came up with a similar approach that solves this problem, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2632616/109451).

Answer (score 1):

First, if you extend $f$ linearly across each triangle, then the resulting function cannot be extended to a smooth function on 3-space unless the triangle all lie in a plane. To put it more bluntly: your problem is ill-posed: you want the gradient of a non-differentiable function.

Perhaps you'll say "Well, just give me the gradient of *any* differentiably function that has those values at those vertices", and again it's ill-posed, for there and infinitely many such functions.

What you really need to do is specify the problem more precisely (which is tough to do). You might, for instance, say "Among all diff'l functions with those values, find the one whose squared gradient magnitude has the smallest integral over the surface". Without *some* such criterion, there's no reasonable answer to your question.

In particular, there's a smooth function $f$, meeting your vertex values, with the property that its gradient at every vertex is zero.

Comment: Pardon my illiteracy in math, but would't the same apply for example to a mesh that is composed of squares, i.e. an image? We can however approximate the gradient in an image very easily. I don't want to find the gradient of the fucntion in the whole domain, just know its value in the nodes of the mesh

Comment: Yes. And when you can say "we can approximate the gradient," you're really saying "Someone else has (perhaps silently) made all the choices that you've asked about, and subject to those choices, we can approximate the gradient..."

Comment: Yes, you are *technically* correct, but I assumed it was clear enough when the question said that I needed a *"numerical approximate of the [..] gradient in the nodes"*.  You think I should edit the question to add the constrain? To be honest, I'd be even happy to explore other cases

Comment: The problem arises when you say "**the** gradient" -- when the *function* is undetermined, the *gradient* is too. So while you *think* you have a gradient question, you really have a question about interpolating functions on meshes.

Comment: I honestly say this without any hostility: I have no idea how much of this answer/comments is you being mathematically anal about my words/problem and how much it is really relevant for the numerical problem at hand. I do understand what you mean, however I am in the same point as in my first comment: Yes, you are right, and at the same time we can find (with some constrains, for sure) robust numerical approximations for e.g. images.

Comment: If you want a better problem definition: I want the same assumptions about $f$ and its gradient as a gradient in an image would do, where $\nabla  p_{i,j}=(\frac{(p_{i+1,j}-p_{i,j})}{dx},\frac{(p_{i,j+1}-p_{i,j})}{dy})$. Use central or back differences in needed

Comment: Most math problems have an *answer*, and we can check that the answer is right. I'm doing my best to turn yours into one of those. That's actually a valuable skill for those who work with mathematics. I'm sorry I can't just "give you the answer", but... that's life. I mean, I *did* give you **an** answer, but I had the decency to point out that it had limitations, and you didn't like those. If you prefer other answers, ones that don't point out their limitations, so be it.

Comment: I liked your answer as much as any of the others, in fact I am testing all of them. I am *genuinely* asking what limitations I should add to the question/ how to understand the limitation at hand so I can improve the problem definition

Comment: Tha information from the deleted answer was interesting, you can add it to this one if you feel like. Wouldn't "How do I formulate a question about computing gradients of real-valued functions interpolated from values at mesh vertices?" be too broad for math.se?

Comment: @JohnHughes and apparently my lack of English may have sounded rude in my third comment: sorry, I suck *also* at English. Just wanted to know if you were being very correct in your maths and how was that related to the problem at hand. sorry.

Comment: You ask *Wouldn't "How do I formulate a question about computing gradients of real-valued functions interpolated from values at mesh vertices?" be too broad for math.se?* It might be, but with an explanation of why just asking for a formula doesn't work, it might be a good and interesting question.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I will sit down, read more on this and try to come with a more defined and solvable problem. I did not realise at the time of posting that the question was not as straightforward as it may seem (to me).